Adding members to MS Entra Group via MS Graph API fails via Python Azure Function App
Setting the scene: I'm trying to add members to a MS Entra Group by calling the MS Graph API from a Python application hosted on an Azure Functions App instance. The application runs on behalf of an SPN that authenticates via a client certificate and has the User.Read.All MS Graph API permission. Furthermore, the SPN is owner of the MS Entra Group. First the app fetches the user' object IDs (I) and then, it adds them to the MS Entra group as members (II).
Problem: If I run the Python logic from my local machine on behalf of the SPN, the members are added to my MS Entra Group. If I run the logic on the Azure Fuction app, the app is able to retrieve the users' object IDs but fails to add the members. The MS Graph API returns: Error: 403, {"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.".
Evironment Variables for DefaultAzureCredential
$env:AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH = ".\cert.pem"
$env:AZURE_CLIENT_ID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
$env:AZURE_TENANT_ID = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"

Python script
import requests, re 
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

class GraphClient:
    def __init__(self, az_credential):
        self._graph_token = az_credential.get_token("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default").token

    def get_members_object_ids(self, members):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self._graph_token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        members = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', members)
        members_ids = []
        for member in members:
            query_params = {
                "$filter": f"mailNickname eq '{member}'"
            }
            try:
                response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=query_params)
                response.raise_for_status()
                members_ids.append(response.json()['value'][0]['id'])
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
        return members_ids
    
    def add_members_to_group(self, group_id, member_ids: list):
        url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/$ref"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self._graph_token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        for member_id in member_ids:
            data = {
                "@odata.id": f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{member_id}"
            }
            try:
                response = requests.post(url=url, json=data, headers=headers)
                response.raise_for_status()
                print(f"Member with id {member_id} added to group with id {group_id}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{response.status_code}: {response.text}")
                raise e
            
members = "Tiger Woods (AAAA), Taylor Swift (BBBB)"
adgr_id = "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222"
          
az_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
graph_client = GraphClient(az_credential)
members_ids = graph_client.get_members_object_ids(members)
graph_client.add_members_to_group(adgr_id, members_ids)

Output Running Locally
If I run the script locally (on behalf of the SPN) everything runs as expected and I receive the following output:

Output Running on Azure Functions
If I run the logic on Azure Functions app in the Azure Cloud, I am able to retrieve the users' object IDs but I receive the following error output once I try to add the MS Entra Group members:

2024-08-28T13:50:04Z   [Information]   CertificateCredential.get_token succeeded
2024-08-28T13:50:04Z   [Information]   EnvironmentCredential.get_token succeeded
2024-08-28T13:50:04Z   [Information]   DefaultAzureCredential acquired a token from EnvironmentCredential
2024-08-28T13:50:05Z   [Error]   403: {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2024-08-28T13:50:04","request-id":"603ee6e0-07b1-44b4-ad82-43b4709aa761","client-request-id":"603ee6e0-07b1-44b4-ad82-43b4709aa761"}}}
2024-08-28T13:50:05Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.create_ad_group' (Failed, Id=25c267f3-49df-4d78-b826-b4de42311f83, Duration=8280ms)

Tokens
I have decoded the tokens and both have the following roles key-value pair:
"roles": [
  "User.Read.All"
],

Is there a way to fix this issue without granting broader API permissions?

What are the Graph API permissions assigned to the Service Principal? Are these application or delegated permissions.

@GauravMantri The MS Graph API permissions are User.Read.All - Application, User.Read - delegated. The SPN is owner of the MS Entra Group so the permissions should be sufficient.

I would recommend decoding the access token and checking the roles/permissions in there. I believe somewhere permissions are not correct and that's why you are getting 403 error.

@GauravMantri, I decoded both the Local and Azure functions JWT and there's only a difference in iat, nbf, exp, aio, uti and xms_idrel. These attributes do not represent permissions.

Could you confirm whether the decoded token has roles or scp claim in it? If yes, please include the values of it and how you passed certificate details in azure function app?

@Sridevi, the decoded tokens have roles and the values only contain the User.Read.All role as expected. However, it should not need additional API permissions as the SPN is owner of the MS Entra Group

How you added certificate in Azure Function App?

Certificate is fetched from a key vault and written to the filesystem and the path is defined in the environment variables. That logic works fine otherwise I would not be able to query the Object IDs of the users by calling the MS Graph API.

At minimum to add members to a group you need the GroupMember.ReadWrite.All All as explained in the docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions
Are you able to share the corelation ID and timestamp of the successful call?
Even though the SPN is the owner of the group, it doesn't necessarily mean it has all the necessary permissions to manage the group.

Hi @bakkie103 Do you have additional function named create_ad_group to create Azure AD group at which error is occurring from this image https://i.sstatic.net/H0J7dLOy.png?

Hi @CarolM, if a principal is the owner of an MS Entra Group, you don't need to have additional API permissions to add members to the group as they are already provided as part of the owner permission set

During the troubleshooting process, I tested using a locally generated token in the Azure Function App, which successfully added members to the group. Subsequently, I used the Azure Function App-generated token in my local environment, and this also resulted in successful member additions. This confirmed that both tokens were functioning correctly.
To address the issue, I introduced a delay in my Python logic between the creation of the MS Entra Group and the addition of members. This resolved the problem, leading me to suspect that the MS Entra Group was not fully provisioned when I initially attempted to call the MS Graph API for adding members.
